# how to get the results in the python shell saved to a variable so they can be used

Tags: python-3.x

at the moment i am trying to add a feature to search for an image url in my code.
i have found the code below but when i run it all the data is displayed (including the url i want) is displayed/printed in the python shell but not saved to a variable.

how can i get it so the url shown in the shell is saved to a vaiable i can then use.

thanks

```
from google_images_download import google_images_download   #importing the library

response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()   #class instantiation

arguments = {"keywords":"air plane","limit":1,"print_urls":True}   #creating list of arguments

paths = response.download(arguments)   #passing the arguments to the function
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it will work but have you tried

```
 var = subprocess.check_output('python file.py',stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
```

this takes the shell output from a python program and stores it. though it think it may only be print() and repr() it will store from.

btw file.py is the file that makes the output that you want.

Comment: hi
thanks for your answer
importing subprocess and putting your suggestion into the bottom of the code returns the error:
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'python images.py' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: i believe that means the your images.py failed to complete. Are you calling it from with in images.py causing a recursion?